# Can someone explain to me why the Horst link patent question was removed?

Tags: discussion

Not even, migrated, just removed. It was a good question that was voted on to reopen. What's the justification?

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/does-the-us-only-patent-on-the-four-bar-linkage-horst-link-suspension-affect-p (need high rep to see post)

Comment: all I see is a removed question. If I need moderator level permissions, I'm still >5k points away.

Answer (score 3):

I temporarily deleted the question to eliminate the bounty that was in place.  The bounty prevented migrating the question.

If you look again, you will see that it has been migrated to Ask Patents.